# Trouble passing AJAX to PHP, gets undefined instead

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable in a script by using AJAX so i can use it in my PHP document. 
The idea was to pass through a value selected using javascript then pass that value to an SQL query

Below i attempted to use AJAX to pass through the variable gender but it prints out undefinied when it should print out male

any help would be appreaciated thanx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

 var gender = 'male';

 $(".generate").click(function(){

  $.ajax({
     url: 'santa.php', //This is the current doc
     type: "GET",
     data: ({gender:gender}),
     success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
     }
});     

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="generate">Generate</button>

<?php

$userAnswer = $_GET['gender']; 

echo $userAnswer;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `<?` for `?>` for properly closing PHP

Comment: ^^ Also the semicolon after `echo $userAnswer;`

Comment: And change the return type. You just echo the gender now, which isn't proper Json, so that might lead to unexpected results when reading data. You can keep it 'json', but make sure to inspect the raw data in the network debugging tools instead of relying on the console.logged data.

Comment: on page load `$userAnswer = $_GET['gender'];` will be set. This will not change once you ajax call has been made, as the whole page will not refresh.

Comment: `type` is already defaulted to `GET`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things going wrong here.

For one thing,  `$(".generate")lick(function(){ ... }`  is being executed before the ".generate" object is defined in the DOM.  This section should be wrapped in a `$(document).ready( )` block so that the click action is only registered *after* the button exists in the DOM.

Then there's the question of getting the AJAX to fire properly.  Another answer had the solution; remove the `dataType` all together.  The parentheses in `data: (gender: gender})` are unnecessary, but harmless.

Finally, a design consideration.  You are using the same script to answer the JSON responses, so when the page first loads, you'll generate a PHP notice that `$_GET['gender']` is undefined (this error might be surpressed depending on your configuration, but I get something like <kbd>Undefined index: gender in...</kbd>). Then when the AJAX response comes through, it's a complete web page with all the Javascript and HTML that's in the orginal doc.

Instead of doing it this way, you would probably want to change your complete response based on whether `$_GET['gender']` is defined.

I've posted a working version, since I had to hack this stuff out myself.  Hope it helps!

```
<?php
if( array_key_exists( 'gender', $_GET ) ){ 
    $userAnswer = $_GET['gender']; 
    echo $userAnswer;
    exit;
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
 var gender = 'male';
$(document).ready( function() {
 $(".generate").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
     url: document.location, //This is the current doc
     type: "GET",
     // dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
     data: ({gender:gender}),
     success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
     }
  });     
 });
});
</script>
</head>
 <body>
    <button class="generate">Generate</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that works bro thanx, but the only issue is PHP picks up the variable as undefined is their anyway i can refresh it when i click generate

Comment: Sure, of course!  Have the PHP write out an *empty* tag into the html with a known ID the first time the page loads, and then instead of `console.log(data)` you'd do something like `$('#gender').html(data)` - but in a real world situation, you'd probably want to pass JSON back to the Javascript side, so that you can have multiple keys and values in that payload.

Answer (score 0):

replace:
`dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
     data: ({gender:gender}),`

To:
     `data: {gender:gender},`

And:

```
<?php

$userAnswer = $_GET['gender']; 

echo $userAnswer;

?>
```

Comment: Parentheses form an expression, they're unnecessary but not the root of the problem.

Comment: `dataType` sets the expected response format, so it should not be included unless you're actually returning JSON from the server.  I couldn't get it to work as is with `dataType` set to `json`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the aJax call as follows

```
 $(".generate").click(function(){

  $.ajax({
     url: 'santa.php', //This is the current doc
     type: "GET",
     data: "gender="+gender, 
     success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
     }
});
```